# Could not autowire field: Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java

After changing an XSD for a perfectly working webservice i came across this error. I changed a field from long to String and the class was generated in my resources folder by the plugin. After deploying the war file i get the error.

I added @Repository on the repository class and also @Component on the handler but i still get the error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could 
not autowire field: private abc.def.Handler abc.def.endpoint.handler; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'HandlerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private abc.def.repository.ConfigRepository abc.def.handler.impl.HandlerImpl.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 95 more


@Endpoint
public class GetEndPoint {

/**
 * The logger instance.
 */
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetEndPoint.class);

/**
 * The namespace uri property.
 */
private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://aba.def/soap";

/**
 * The ServiceHandler instance.
 */
@Autowired
private GetHandler handler;


@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getRequest")
public
@ResponsePayload
GetResponse getQuery(@RequestPayload final GetRequest request) {
    if (request == null) {
        LOGGER.error("Null request object");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("request = null");
    }
    try {
        return handler.getQuery(request);
    } catch (final Exception exception) {
        LOGGER.error(String.format("UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: %s",
                        exception.getMessage()),
                exception);
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }

}
```

}

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"id",
"working"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "getProviderStatementResponse")
public class GetResponse {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String id; // changed this to String from long
protected boolean working;

// getters and setters
```

I need to deploy without error and query the and points. how can i get rid of this error?

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation`: that means you're using incompatible versions of Spring jars.

Comment: @JB Nizet In my pom i am using spring-data-jpa 1.11.12.RELEASE and Springframework -4.0.6.Release. What should i change to for both to be compatible? I am confused because all i did was to change the XSD.

Comment: The documentation of your version of spring-data-jpa (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.12.RELEASE/reference/html/#dependencies.spring-framework) says: *require Spring Framework in version 4.3.17.RELEASE or better*